# Variable Increase in MS PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint

I've very limited knowledge of PowerPoint but have been asked to create a presentation slide where I would have to click areas on a map and that would change color and increment a number (population). I am able to change the color of the map on click and I'm able to display a bubble but I am not able to increment the population number based on the areas of the map that are clicked.

I've looked at some solutions around here and did some research online but couldn't find anything that would point me in the right direction.

Is there a way to create a variable and pass a number when you click a specific area of the map, which is a Freeform.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: This can be done with VBA in the presentation file, but for security reasons, some users either won't or can't open presentations that include VBA. You'll want to find out who'll be using this presentation and whether they allow opening presentations that include VBA aka Macros. Also, will the users be on Mac or Windows versions of PowerPoint?  In this case, it matters.  Will they be viewing the presentation via an online version of PowerPoint?  In that case, VBA/Macros won't work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Steve, the users will most likely be using Windows, however there might be one user the CEO which will use a Mac. It will be done locally. I looked into VBA but couldn't find how to add it. Any chance you could point me in the right direction Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set each shape's Action Setting to Run Macro: (macro name) 
That will run the VBA subroutine called (macro name) when you click on the shape during a slide show.

Mac PowerPoint has a few bugs that keep this from working as smoothly as it does in Windows PowerPoint but the code below works around these issues and works in either version.

```
Sub IncrementNumber(oSh as Shape)

   Dim oSl as Slide
   Dim oShTemp as Shape

   ' oSh.Parent returns a valid reference to the shape's host slide:  
   Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(oSh.Parent.SlideIndex)
   ' and oSh.Name works as well

   ' So we use those two bits to get a reference 
   ' to the clicked shape like so
   Set oShTemp = oSl.Shapes(oSh.Name)
   With oShTemp
       .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = _
       Cstr(CLng(oShTemp.TextRange.Text) + 1)
   End With

End Sub
```

About this bit:

```
Cstr(CLng(oShTemp.TextRange.Text) + 1)
```

This gets the current text in the shape, converts it from text (string) to a number so we can do arithmetic on it, adds 1 to it, then converts it back to text so we can plug it back into the shape's text.

If you don't know what to do with VBA code examples, there's a tutorial on the PowerPoint FAQ site that I maintain:

How do I use VBA code in PowerPoint
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00033_How_do_I_use_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint.htm

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful explanation Steve. Really appreciate it.